# Output nested set for Google Visualisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, google-visualization

I am using Baum for Laravel to retrieve a nested set, but I can't begin to think how to get it into the format that my Google organisation chart needs it.

The outputted JSON:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "id":1,
      "parent_id":null,
      "lft":1,
      "rgt":10,
      "depth":0,
      "name":"Jing's Team",
      "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"2016-01-24 18:32:22",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "id":2,
            "parent_id":1,
            "lft":2,
            "rgt":3,
            "depth":1,
            "name":"Ann's Team",
            "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at":"2016-01-24 18:32:22",
            "children":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "parent_id":1,
            "lft":4,
            "rgt":9,
            "depth":1,
            "name":"Mike's Team",
            "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at":"2016-01-24 18:32:22",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "id":4,
                  "parent_id":3,
                  "lft":5,
                  "rgt":8,
                  "depth":2,
                  "name":"Laidy's Team",
                  "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
                  "updated_at":"2016-01-24 18:32:22",
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "id":5,
                        "parent_id":4,
                        "lft":6,
                        "rgt":7,
                        "depth":3,
                        "name":"Steve's Team",
                        "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
                        "updated_at":"2016-01-24 18:32:22",
                        "children":[  

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Which is generated with:

```
    Team::rebuild(true);
    $nodes = Team::where('id', Auth::user()->team_id)->first();
    $nodes = $nodes->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toHierarchy();

    return view('team.index', ['nodes' => $nodes]);
```

The way that Google organisation takes it:

```
data.addRows([
    [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'},
        '', 'The President'],
    [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'},
        'Mike', 'VP'],
    ['Sam', 'Mike', ''],
    ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
    ['Phil', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
    ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
]);
```

['NAME', 'PARENT_NAME', 'HOVER OVER TITLE']

How can parse the JSON to get it into the format that Google needs it?

---

So far I have:

```
public function index()
{
    Team::rebuild(true);
    $nodes = Team::where('id', Auth::user()->team_id)->first();
    $nodes = $nodes->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toHierarchy();

    $data = [];
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $data[] = [$node->name, '', ''];
        $data = $this->parseChildNode($node, $data);
    }

    return view('team.index', ['nodes' => json_encode($data)]);
}
protected $i = 0;
protected function parseChildNode($node, $data)
{
    if ($node->children()->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($node->children as $child) {
            $data[] = [$child->name, $data[$this->i][0], ''];
            $data = $this->parseChildNode($child, $data);
        }
        $this->i++;
        return $data;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

But it only goes down two levels and no further :(

---

I am now getting (everything is under "Jing's Team" which is incorrect):

```
[["Jing's Team","",""],["Ann's Team","Jing's Team",""],["Mike's Team","Jing's Team",""],["Laidy's Team","Jing's Team",""],["Steve's Team","Jing's Team",""]]
```

With the above altered code.

Comment: you aren't catching the return of `$this->parseChildNode($child, $data);` inside the same function. Note how whenever you call it elsewhere it returns to a variable

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks but now everyone is under "Jing's Team", please see my edit.

Comment: but everything in original data is under Jing's team. Try `$data[] = $this->parseChildNode($child, $data);`

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, but Laidys and Steves team are within Mikes team (inside Mikes team's lft and rgt). Steves is then within Laidys.

Comment: Not really clear to me why so much nesting of teams within teams. And how that only ends up being 2 teams

Comment: @charlietfl It may be easier to think of it as positions within an organisation. Ann and Mike work for Jing, no one works for Ann, Laidy works for Mike and Steve works for Laidy.

Comment: ok..org chart so to speak. Well anyway what you did was overwrite `$data` so the line above with `$data[]` is gone and since it's in a loop, will end up overwriting each iteration also. Have a link to google demo for this?

Comment: If I change it to just $this->parseChildNode($child, $data); it won't go past Mike and Ann to process their children :(.

Comment: right...because the return needs to be captured but your original expected results is pretty flat so i'm not sure how it relates to all thise deep nesting

Comment: @charlietfl This is the code I have tried to adapt initially: https://gist.github.com/etrepat/6920301 The difference is, is that I'm trying to build an array.

Comment: Yeah that's relatively simple because it;s not recursive. I think you have another issue because `$i` is outside but your data isn't going to be flat. I do a lot of this in javascript mostly .... just not 100% clear what final data needs to look like. Link to whatever google api chart this is would help

Comment: @charlietfl https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?hl=en

Comment: @WhiteHat PHP please because I want to cache it later as result sets could be very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to works with your use case, biggest issue was `$data[$this->i][0]`

```
public function index()
{
    Team::rebuild(true);
    $node = Team::where('id', Auth::user()->team_id)->first();
    $nodes = $nodes->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toHierarchy();

    $data = [];
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $data[] = [$node->name, '', ''];
        $data = $this->parseNodesChildren($node, $data);
    }

    return view('team.index', ['nodes' => json_encode($data)]);
}
protected function parseNodesChildren($node, &$data)
{       
    if ($node->children->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($node->children as $child) {
            $data[] = [$child->name, $node->name, ''];
            $this->parseNodesChildren($child, $data);
        }
    }
}
```